# Missing package 'play.filters.cors.CORSFilter' - Play Framework 2.4.6 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, cors

I am trying to add a CORS Filter to my Play Framework REST API. I added a Filters class, as per the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/CorsFilter), however it cannot seem to find the following package at all, I have searched high and low and no luck:

```
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
```

And the Filter class:

```
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    @Inject
    CORSFilter corsFilter;

    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] { corsFilter };
    }
}
```

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa,
  filters,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.7.Final",
  "org.projectlombok" % "lombok-maven" % "1.16.6.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1207.jre7",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-jpa" % "1.9.2.RELEASE",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"

)
```

Where is this package?

Comment: Did you added the `filters` dependency in your build.sbt?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not finding? Your project fails to compile your IDE does not recognize the class?

Comment: @marcospereira I sure did, check the updated question with build.sbt included..

The IDE does not seem to recognise the class.

Comment: @marcospereira I invalidated IntelliJ and did a complete resync and it worked...thanks :)

Comment: Try to turn auto-import on. That way, IDEA will update your project dependencies when you add/remove something to your build.sbt.

Comment: @marcospereira The thing is, it is on and everything previously had been added :S

Answer (score 1):

Use `activator eclipse` command in terminal as like `activator run`.

Its resolve my problem, hope its also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

in your build.sbt file just add this line.

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

as explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter).